# Getting custom size image URL

Tags: images

I added custom image size like below.

```
add_image_size( 'team-member', 220, 220, true );
```

I can get this image like below in the post.

```
the_post_thumbnail( 'team-member' );
```

But how can I get image URL if it's outside of loop. For example, is there any way to get image URL like this and use it inside shortcode?

```
<img src="http://URL.../member1-220x220.jpg">
```

UPDATE:

For now, I'm getting it like below. Is there any better solution?

```
$image_extension = substr( $image, -4 );
$image = str_replace( $image_extension, '-220x220' . $image_extension, $image);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with a piece of the code from the "Post Thumbnail Linking to large Image Size" example on the [get_the_post_thumbnail](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail) page (using [wp_get_attachment_image_src](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src)):

```
<?php
$image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'team-member' );
// actual URL = $image_url[0];
?>
```